# find duplicated csv columns from list [python pandas]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to find duplicate columns from a list, so not just any columns.

example of correct csv looks like this:

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, custom, custom
1,2,3,4,test,test
4,3,2,1,test,test
```

list looks like this:

```
columnNames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
```

So when I run something like `df.columns.duplicated()` I don't want to it detect the duplicate 'custom' fields, only if there is more than one 'col1' column, or more than one 'col2' column, etc, and return True when one of those columns is found to be duplicated.

I found when including a duplicate 'colN' column name, col4 in the example, and I print it out, it shows me that `index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col4.1'], dtype='object')`

No idea how to write that line of code.

Comment: Please include your expected output

Comment: @Sushanth I want  'True' to be returned when a duplicate from the columnNames list is found in the csv. So assuming there is a second 'col1' in the my example csv, it would return True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) + [`Index.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) to create a boolean mask:

```
c = df.columns.str.rsplit('.', n=1).str[0]
mask = c.isin(columnNames) & c.duplicated()
```

If want to find duplicated column names use [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) with this `mask`:

```
dupe_cols = df.columns[mask]
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. when i print(mask) after the first instruction, they're all False.

Answer (score 0):

When u will read this csv file using pandas u will not get any of the two columns with same name. As I know, second custom column name  will get replaced by custom.1, so u can get idea from that how many duplicates are there

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do it using  a list comprehension:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,3,4,"test","test"],[4,4,3,2,1,"test","test"]],
columns = ["col1", "col1.1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "custom", "custom"])

print(df)
Out[1]:
    col1  col1.1  col2  col3  col4 custom custom
0     1     1     2     3     4   test   test
1     4     4     3     2     1   test   test

columnNames = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
splitColumns = pd.Index([i.split('.')[0] for i in df.columns])


[False if col not in columnNames else dup for col, dup in zip(splitColumns, splitColumns.duplicated())]


Out[2]: [False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: I tried this as well out of curiosity and it did not work, returned all False

Comment: @blindside044, you are right It would return all False if the columns did not have the same name. I added the split logic to detect the renamed columns.